# How to create an Angular 6+ component containerless?

Tags: angular

I wrote a very simple component based on Bootstrap 4 by Angular 7.
The final result is:
[image]
[image]

Everything work perfectly but in Aurelia, we can create a component **containerless**.
It is necessary for creating other components based on Bootstrap 4 that can not wrap into a non-bootstrap div element. (Angular div)

How can I remove the container of an Angular element and render just inside of it?

[image]

Comment: you really can't in angular 6.  They had this capability in angular js but removed it in agnular 2+.  ngBootstrap is designed to work with angular though and there are little things you can do to the css of components to make them work correctly. It is annoying but ends up being a minor inconvenience in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: You absolutely can, by using an attribute selector for your component. Something like `selector: "[appFoo]"`

Comment: I want to create a component, not an attribute for a component. I want to have a containerless component, not an attribute to extend current functionalities.

Comment: @HF_67 you're disregarding Ingo's suggestion, but I really don't understand why. It solves your problem. Instead of using <at-alert>, you just use <div at-alert>, and the template of your component will render inside that div. So if your template is "This is an alert message", you'll have the result you want. That said, I don't really understand why it's a problem to have an at-alert element in the first place.

Comment: @HF_67 I didn't say create a directive, I said create a component with an attribute selector. Just try it out and see for yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot really just *omit* the surrounding container, no. However, you can create a component with an attribute selector:

```
@Component({
  selector: "[appFoo]",
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
})
export class AppFooComponent {}
```

You use it like this:

```
<div appFoo>Hello!</div>
```

That way you can decide what the surrounding container should be when using the component. You can also further restrict your selector to things such as `div[appFoo]` etc.

---

Note: By default, the codelyzer rules in an Angular CLI project will give you a linting error for this because it requires components to use component selectors, but you can just disable this in your tslint config.

Comment: Is this a bad practice? Could doing this cause any problems?

Comment: There are cases where this is unavoidable, apart from those I'd usually use a component selector. Whether it is bad practice is an opionated topic.